# Preserving color on breadcrumb item click

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I have a working demo of breadcrumbs here in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/1/)

Below is the code

HTML

```
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#crumbs ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background: #3498db;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 40px 0 80px;
}

#crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 40px solid #3498DB;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 40px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #fa5ba5;
}

#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #fa5ba5;
}
```

Css has pink color for mouse hover but what i actually want to do is to preserve that color once any item on breadcrumbs is clicked ie: the pink color should remain after a click which can act as a signal to user as of which tab in breadcrumb is currently active.

I have tried using :active in css but it does not preserve the color on breadcrumbs after click.

Any help ?

Comment: jquery: $('#crumbs li').click(function(){$(this).css({background: "#fa5ba5"})})

Comment: thanks..but i am not using jquery anywhere in my application....how to do it with pure javascript ?

Comment: Corum's answer seems better than mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `:visited` selector. Something like this will work well :

```
#crumbs ul li a:visited {
  background-color: #fa5ba5;
}

#crumbs ul li a:visited:after {
    border-left-color: #fa5ba5;
}
```

And the JS Fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/2/)

**EDIT (Full JS method):**

You can find the full JS demo in the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/7/).
In `onclick` event, there is a loop which remove class `.onclick` from previous active link.

Code provided must be improved, it's just to show you it can work.

I highly recommend you to use a library like jQuery, because DOM manipulation in native JS code is very boring.

To show you the difference, with jQuery you would have to do this :

HTML Code :

```
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="link" href="#1">One</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#2">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {   
    $('.onclick').removeClass('onclick'); // Remove class from previous active link
    $(this).addClass('onclick'); // Add class to new active link 
});
```

Comment: That solves the problem of preserving the color but i want the color to be active only on one tab which is clicked ie:the previously clicked tab should not have the color so as it gives the feel of single tab active at a time.

Comment: I have edited my post : you can add a class to your element on click event.

Comment: i edited my fiddle to capture click event..not working what am i supposedly doing wrong there ?
http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/5/

Comment: Also have a doubt using the click event for solution...how would i be able to reset the color on previously clicked tab after a new tab is clicked ?

Comment: I have edited my post to add a JSFiddle link that show you how to reset color of previous selected tab.

Comment: thanks a lot @Corum your code fits in perfectly...here is the updated working breadcrumbs Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/9/ :)