# Shop Stages & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on my online shop, and I want to add stages, like in the picture below:

[image: What I want my list to finally look like]

My problem is getting one of the stages to be highlighted, depending on the page it should be shown on.  I had a standard div and ul in my HTML:

```
<div id='stages'>
    <ul>
        <li class='selected'>Cart</li>
        <li>Your Details</li>
        <li>Summary</li>
        <li>Payment</li>
        <li>Complete</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS (so far):

```css
div#stages {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#stages > ul > li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
} 
#stages > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #DDD url(/img/bin/bg-steps.png) no-repeat top right;
    margin: -3px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
#stages > ul > li.selected {
    background: #306bb4 url(/img/bin/bg-steps.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}
#stages > ul > li:last-child {
    background: #DDD!important;
    padding-right: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Originally using the image 'bg-steps.png':

[image]

Which looks nice.  However to get an item selected is proving to be too hard, because it needs a different image at the begining of the LI and at the end.  Can anyone help/simplify this for me?  [See here for a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7x7P8/)

**EDIT**:  This is my aim: [image]

Comment: What is your problem? You need colored image and replace it when selected. Use background-color instead of background to not override the image. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x7P8/1/)

Comment: You need an image with a blue arrow if you want to make it works.

Comment: @Corum How would a blue arrow help this? Because the arrows need to be white, the background of the LI's need to be blue...:S

Comment: I'm not sure to have correctly understood your need... If you want to change your grey arrow into a blue arrow for selected item, you need an additional image with a blue arrowhead.

Comment: @Corum I have posted an image as to where I want to get to.

Comment: @Chud37 : with your edit, I confirm you need a third image with blue arrowhead if you want to make it works with images. You also can use CSS3 to make this without any images. You can see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/7/) I have made to this question [Preserving color on breadcrumb item click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976685/preserving-color-on-breadcrumb-item-click/18976814#18976814). Problem is not the same, but you can use the code to create your arrows.

Comment: @Chud37 : Code needs to be improved, but there is a full working example in CSS3 : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/13/).

Comment: @Corum WOW! thank you so much, I wasn't expecting a full CSS answer.  That is really really helpful.  Please put it as an answer!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x7P8/6/)

Here I added some pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`

In here you do not need your pictures in the `background` and it is made in PURE css and html

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3, you don't need to use images.

It can be achieve using a pure CSS solution with pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`.
You can use it to generate triangles before and after each `li` element.

You can find a full working example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RH5Pc/13/).

I have used a similar trick in one of my project, and it's well supported in FF, Chrome and IE10. For other browsers, you need to check yourself because I don't test them.